# Простейшая запись в базу без проверки

Tags: php, sql

Если это простейшая запись в базу данных на PHP:

**XXX.php:**

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)";
```

то чем и как правильно обозначить эти VALUES в html-форме, которую заполняет пользователь? каким атрибутом?

**form.html:**

```
<form action="ХХХ.php" method="post" name="...">
<p><input type="text" name="..." value="..." placeholder="..."></p>
...
<p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VALUES это данные которые будут записаны в таблицы.
Сперва вводим имя табилцы после VALUES переменную(Данный полученный из форумы).

```
$sql="INSERT INTO forma (username) VALUES ('переменная')";
```

XXX.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['otpravka']))
{
//Принимаем отплавленное с форума
$imya = $_POST['username'];
$familya = $_POST['surname'];
$soobshenie = $_POST['message'];

$sql="INSERT INTO forma (username, surname, message) VALUES ('$imya', '$familya', '$soobshenie')";
}
```

form.html:

```
<form action="ХХХ.php" method="post" name="form">
<p><input type="text" name="username"  placeholder="Введите имя"></p>
<p><input type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Введите фамилию"></p>
<textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Введите Сообщение"></textarea>
...
<p><input type="submit" name="otpravka" value="Отправить"></p>
```

http://www.quizful.net/post/simplest-form-html-css

Начинай с ютуба искать что как быстро выучишь PHP

Comment: _Никогда_ не предлагайте решения с непосредственной подстановкой значений переменных в текст запроса. И так 80% взломов сайтов в интернете из за такого кода, Не надо учить людей делать не правильно и его приумножать. _Всегда_ используйте привязываемые переменные http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @Mike прошу пояснить, что имеется в виду под "непосредственной подстановкой значений переменных в текст запроса"?

Comment: @losew Представьте, что вам в переменной `$_POST['message']` подсунут текст `a'),('xxx',(select password from user where name='admin'),'a`. В итоге так как значение переменной окажется непосредственно в тексте запроса в $sql в БД будут вставлены 2 записи, вместо одной и во второй из них в качестве фамилии окажется пароль пользователя admin. понятно что имена полей и таблиц будут подбирать, но в итоге подберут. Если же использовать привязку переменных в тексте запроса будет `?` или `:msg`, а значение переменной будет безопасным образом записано в БД как есть

Comment: Но нельзяже новичка учить сразу к защите пусть сперва изучет PHP далее уже SQL INJECTION.